# Solving TSP using dynamic programming in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, traveling-salesman

I've found many resources online, discussing this and related topics, but I haven't found anything that really helps me know where to start with implementing this solution.

To clarify, starting from city 0, I need to visit every other city once, and return back to city 0.

I have an array such as this one:

```
   0 1129 1417 1240 1951
1129    0 1100  800 2237
1417 1100    0 1890 3046
1240  800 1890    0 1558
1951 2237 3046 1558    0
```

Along with finding the optimal route, I need to also find the optimal partial routes along the way. For example, I'd start with routes of length 2, and end up printing out something like this:

```
S = {0,1}
C({0,1},1) = 1129

S = {0,2}
C({0,2},2) = 1417

S = {0,3}
C({0,3},3) = 1240

S = {0,4}
C({0,4},4) = 1951
```

Then I'd go to routes of length 3, and print something like this:

```
S = {0,1,2}
C({0,1,2},1) = 2517
C({0,1,2},2) = 2229
and so on...
```

To make this a dynamic programming solution, I assume I should be saving the shortest distance between any n nodes, and the best way I've thought to do that is with a Hashmap, where the key would be an integer value of every node included in that path, in ascending order (A path going from nodes 0>1>3>4 or 0>1>4>3 could be stored as '134'), and each key would hold a pair that could store the path order as a List, and the total distance as an integer.

At this point I would think I'd want to calculate all paths of distance 2, then all of distance 3, and then take the smallest few and use the hashmap to find the shortest path back for each, and compare.

Does this seem like it could work? Or am I completely on the wrong track?

Comment: Here's my solution on another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47499540/2203569

Answer (score 1):

You're sort of on track.  Dynamic programming isn't the way to calculate a TSP.  What you're sort of close to is calculating a minimum spanning tree.  This is a tree that connects all nodes using the shortest possible sum of edges.  There are two algorithms that are frequently used: Primm's, and Kruskal's.  They produce something similar to your optimal partial routes list.  I'd recommend you look at Primm's algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm

The easiest way of solving TSP is by finding the minimum spanning tree, and then doing a pre-order tree walk over the tree.  This gives you an approximate travelling salesman solution, and is known as the Triangle Inequality Approximation.  It's guaranteed to be no more than twice as long as an optimal TSP, but it can be calculated much faster.  This web page explains it fairly well  http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/AproxAlgor/TSP/tsp.htm

If you want a more optimal solution, you'll need to look at Christofide's method, which is more complicated.

Comment: Can it really be called "solving TSP" if you have an approximation? Also you can solve TSP using DP (in practice only for tiny instances, there are more scalable ways)

Comment: It would seem that none of those methods use a dynamic programming approach, correct? Unfortunately it's a requirements for this project. Here's the closest thing I've found to what I'm trying to do, but to be honest it has been difficult to fully understand   https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-the-traveling-salesman-problem-using-dynamic-programming

Comment: The maximum number of nodes this will be run with is 5-8 by the way.

Comment: Right, I wasn't too sure how important the 'Dyamic Programming' bit in your question was.  O(n^2.2n) is definitely an expensive solution.

Comment: Christofides' method and the minimum-spanning tree algorithm (or the triangle inequality approximation, as @AndyN calls it) are indeed both heuristics. They are really interesting from a theoretical perspective but there are other better heuristics out there.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

I think you're getting at the fact that the DP recursion itself only tells you the optimal *cost* for each S and j, not the *node* that attained that cost. The classical way to handle this is through "backtracking": once you found out that, for example, `C({0,1,2,3,4},-) = 10000`, you figure out which node attained that cost; let's say it's 3. Then you figure out which node attained `C({0,1,2,3,4},3)`; let's say it's 1. Then you figure out which node attained `C({0,1,2,4},1)`; let's say it's 2, ... and so on. This is the classical way and it avoids having to store a lot of intermediate data. For DPs with a small state space, it's easier just to store all those optimizers along the way. In your case you have an exponentially large state space so it might be expensive to store all of those optimizers, but you already have to store an equally large data structure (`C`), so most likely you can store the optimizers as well. Your intermediate solution of storing a few of the best could work -- then if the backtracking routine turns out to need one you didn't store you can just calculate it the classical way -- seems reasonable, but I'm not sure it's worth the extra coding vs. a pure backtracking approach.

One clarification: You don't actually want to "calculate all paths of distance 2, then all of distance 3, ...", but rather you want to enumerate all *sets* of size 2, then all *sets* of size 3, etc. Still exponential, but not as bad as enumerating all paths.